# Container filesystem is empty when deploying k8s application with Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, minikube, kompose

I have a small web application (a Rails app called `sofia`) that I'm deploying locally with `minikube`.

When I create the k8s resources and run my deployment, the containers do not contain any of the files that were supposed to be copied over during the image build process.

Here's what I'm doing:

### Dockerfile

As part of the `Dockerfile` build, I copy the contents of my local cloned repository into the image working directory:

```
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
```

### The (old) `docker-compose` setup

Historically I've used a `docker-compose` file to run this application and all its services. I map my local directory to the container's working directory (see `volumes:` below). This is a nice convenience when working locally since all changes are reflected "live" inside the container:

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
sofia:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        RAILS_ENV: development
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:sekrit@postgres/
    image: sofia/sofia:local
    ports:
      - # ...
    volumes:
      - .:/app  #<---- HERE
```

### Building k8s resource file with `kompose`

In order to run this on `minikube`, I use the [`kompose` tool](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose) that Kubernetes themselves provide in order to transform my `docker-compose` file into a k8s resource file that can be consumed.

```sh
$ kompose convert --file docker-compose.yml --out k8s.yml --with-kompose-annotation=false
WARN Volume mount on the host "/Users/jeeves/git/jeeves/sofia" isn't supported - ignoring path on the host
INFO Kubernetes file "k8s.yml" created
```

As you can see, it generates a warning that my local volume can not be mounted against the remote volume. This makes sense since a k8s deployment runs "remotely", so I just ignore the warning.

### Running

Finally I run the above resources with k8s / `minikube`

```sh
minikube start
kubectl apply -f k8s.yml
```

I notice the `sofia` container keeps crashing and restarting so I check the logs:

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/sofia-6668945bc8-x9267       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          10s
pod/postgres-fc84cbd4b-dqbrh     1/1     Running            0          10s
pod/redis-cbff75fbb-znv88        1/1     Running            0          10s

$ kubectl logs pod/sofia-6668945bc8-x9267
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

That error is Ruby/Rails specific, but the underlying cause is that there **are no files in the container**! I can confirm this by entering the container and checking files with `ls` - it is indeed empty.

### Questions

1. If the `sofia/sofia:latest` image is correctly built with the `COPY`-ied file contents, why would it dissapear when runing the container on `minikube`?
2. What should I do to ensure my files get copied over correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Volumes are not behaving the same way in Docker in docker-compose and K8s. Kompose can't perfectly translate volume.
In Docker with docker-compose, your declared volume keep the existing files from the directory, while in k8s, a volume is created empty and shadow the existing content.

There is no direct equivalent of docker-compose volumes that keeps existing files in k8s, you will have to work around that with one of the following options, depending on what makes sense in your use case:

- leverage [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) to add your files to this app volume  (if needed, use subPath). Probably ok for a handfull of config files if that's what lives your app directory when the container starts
- in your dockerfile, use COPY to something like app-tmp, then in your entrypoint script copy those files from that app-tmp directory to your "app" volume
- Refactor your application so that it uses "app1" directory (without volumes) with existing files, "app2" starts empty and is used as your volume.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Is there any way I can have `kompose` just ignore that specific volume (the `volumes\n- .:/app` in `docker-compose.yml`) entirely? That line exists only for convenience in `development`, and that volume isn't really needed when deploying with k8s.

Comment: I couldn't find anything built in for that use case, I guess you would need a wrapper bash script or something similar that comment out those volumes in your docker-compose.yml file on the fly (with `sed`?), before calling kompose.